# Text changing after a few seconds http.responseText, .innerHTML (Javascript, Ajax)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using this bit of code to display a message to the user when they try to delete a category which contains a product from a MYSQL Database displayed via a HTML website:

```
function  deleteCategory()
{
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "/637415/admin/scripts/deleteCategory.php"; 
var params = "selectCatDelete=" + document.getElementById("selectedCatDelete").value;
console.log("The value is:",  params);
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.responseText == 0 && http.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("responseText").innerHTML = "You need to delete products from the category, go to the delete products page here: <a href='/637415/admin/deleteProduct.php'>Delete produy</a>";
    }
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("responseText").innerHTML = "Category deleted";
    }

}
http.send(params);
console.log(params);
```

}

The text changes but after a few seconds it disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the rest of your code, it could be related to that location.reload() you have. As soon as you reload the page, any changes you made using javascript will be lost, inlcuding your message.

Comment: I have added more code. I have removed the location.reload(). The problem I have now is that I can't validate the response from the PHP server. IF the MYSQL query fails to execute, I want to display the message.

Comment: If the SQL query in the PHP code fails you can return a string with the error message in it, or you could return -1.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you show the message after the request is completed. See if this works:

```
http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
   //if there is a request not initialized error:

    //Request finished and response is ready
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
      if(http.responseText == 0 ) {
        document.getElementById("responseText").innerHTML = "You need to delete 
        products from the category first, go to the delete products page here: 
        <a href='/637415/admin/deleteProduct.php'>Delete Products</a>";
        }else

        location.reload(); 

        }
}
```

Comment: I get ReferenceError: deleteCategory is not defined when trying this bit of code. I have added more code to the initial post if it helps.